How are cockpit warning sounds recorded/chosen?
I know that during an emergency, sounds in a cockpit such as "TERRAIN PULL UP" are played or in some planes the stick shaker takes place during a stall. But how are such warning sounds and actions decided and/or recorded?

Like most things in aviation, they started out as something somebody thought was a good idea. Then once you try to put it in an aircraft, the regulatory agency (e.g., FAA) has to review it and put their spin on it. Eventually it gets codified in the regulations or specific equipment standards.
At the aircraft level, the rule is 14 CFR 25.1322 Flight Crew Alerting. It currently reads:

§ 25.1322 Flightcrew alerting.
(a) Flightcrew alerts must:
(1) Provide the flightcrew with the information needed to:
(i) Identify non-normal operation or airplane system conditions, and
(ii) Determine the appropriate actions, if any.
(2) Be readily and easily detectable and intelligible by the
flightcrew under all foreseeable operating conditions, including
conditions where multiple alerts are provided.
(3) Be removed when the alerting condition no longer exists.
(b) Alerts must conform to the following prioritization hierarchy
based on the urgency of flightcrew awareness and response.
(1) Warning: For conditions that require immediate flightcrew
awareness and immediate flightcrew response.
(2) Caution: For conditions that require immediate flightcrew
awareness and subsequent flightcrew response.
(3) Advisory: For conditions that require flightcrew awareness and may
require subsequent flightcrew response.
(c) Warning and caution alerts must:
(1) Be prioritized within each category, when necessary.
(2) Provide timely attention-getting cues through at least two
different senses by a combination of aural, visual, or tactile
indications.
(3) Permit each occurrence of the attention-getting cues required by
paragraph (c)(2) of this section to be acknowledged and suppressed,
unless they are required to be continuous.
(d) The alert function must be designed to minimize the effects of
false and nuisance alerts. In particular, it must be designed to:
(1) Prevent the presentation of an alert that is inappropriate or
unnecessary.
(2) Provide a means to suppress an attention-getting component of an
alert caused by a failure of the alerting function that interferes
with the flightcrew's ability to safely operate the airplane. This
means must not be readily available to the flightcrew so that it could
be operated inadvertently or by habitual reflexive action. When an
alert is suppressed, there must be a clear and unmistakable
annunciation to the flightcrew that the alert has been suppressed.
(e) Visual alert indications must:
(1) Conform to the following color convention:
(i) Red for warning alert indications.
(ii) Amber or yellow for caution alert indications.
(iii) Any color except red or green for advisory alert indications.
(2) Use visual coding techniques, together with other alerting
function elements on the flight deck, to distinguish between warning,
caution, and advisory alert indications, if they are presented on
monochromatic displays that are not capable of conforming to the color
convention in paragraph (e)(1) of this section.
(f) Use of the colors red, amber, and yellow on the flight deck for
functions other than flightcrew alerting must be limited and must not
adversely affect flightcrew alerting.

There is also a companion Advisory Circular, AC 25.1322-1 that provides more detailed guidance.
If you look at the rule, it requires "timely attention-getting cues through at least two different senses by a combination of aural, visual, or tactile indications." In most cases, aural and visual cues are used. Stall warning alerts that use a horn and the stick shaker would be an example of aural and tactile cues.
As the rule states, the alerts must be prioritized based on the urgency: Warning, Caution, and Advisory.
Advisory alerts are the lowest category and don't require immediate action. They typically employ a single "Alert" chime and an advisory message on the Crew Alerting System (CAS) display.
When you get to Caution and Warning alerts, it's important to get the right information to the crew so they can act on it in a timely manner. Generally, there are Master Warning and Master Caution lights along with a distinct chime. For many system faults, you'll get the Master Warning or Caution and an associated CAS message (in Red or Amber).
Some warnings you really need to address quickly. These often use the distinct aural alerts you mentioned. Specifically, there are two kinds of aural alerts; non-verbal and verbal. Most of the earliest alerts use non-verbal aurals; stall warning horn, fire bell, overspeed clacker, a/p disconnect tone, etc. While many are based in the limited technology of the times, they all have two big advantages; they convey the message quickly and they can coexist with other aural alerts. This is important when urgency is paramount.
The voice alerts are more recent and the majority are related to three warning systems: Terrain Alerting and Warning System (TAWS), Windshear alerting, and Aircraft Collision Avoidance System (ACAS or alternately known as TCAS.) The key value of the voice alert for warnings is that it doesn't tell you there's a problem, it tells the crew the immediate action they should take -- "PULL UP! PULL UP!". There are a few voice alerts used for Cautions such as the ACAS "TRAFFIC" alert.
The voice alerts for these systems are defined in the TSO standards for the systems. They have evolved over the years as part of the continuing regulatory process between the regulatory agency and the aircraft and equipment manufacturers.
The one downside to voice alerts is that you can only have one at a time. Having more than one at a time could cause interpretation errors and confusion. So the rule requires strict prioritization of the aural alerts and is subject to regulatory approval.
As to how they are implemented; it's just somebody hired to record the messages which are then digitized and stored in the equipment where the software can call up and play the appropriate message.

"Rule requires strict prioritization of the aural alerts and is subject to regulatory approval."
and still when on approach PIA 8303 landed without gear down... sink rate got more priority than GEAR NOT DOWN.
